# .htaccess Error, Forbidden 403

Tags: .htaccess, litespeed

I set .htaccess like :

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*).html$ news.php?id=$1&content=$2 [QSA,L]
```

and result work like :

```
http://example.com/399/tutorial-centos.html
```

But, if i try :

```
http://example.com/399/.html
```

or

```
http://example.com/399/.tutorial-centos.html
```

i got error :

```
403 Forbidden
Access to this resource on the server is denied! Powered By LiteSpeed Web Server
LiteSpeed Technologies is not responsible for administration and contents of this web site!
```

i've tried put it on .htaccces :

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
```

But still got error :(
How to fix it ?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: hellow, anyone can help me ?

Comment: What did you want to happen when a user goes to a page that does not exist, go to the news.php file or show a custom 403 error page?

Comment: I try open : www.example.com/333/.html

And appear error :403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied! on the same url.